# Where to find a real Pokemon XD: Gale of Darkness rom so I can play on the wii and how to set it up

Tags: nintendo-wii, pokemon-series

I have never used pokemon rom before on my wii and im scared to break it. So I need to know where to find a legit website to get the Pokemon XD: Gale of Darkness rom and I also need to know how to set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Unfortunately, this is not possible.

There is no way to download a legitimate copy of *Pokémon XD: Gale of Darkness* on Wii, for following reasons:

- It is a NGC (Nintendo GameCube) game, and Nintendo has yet to sell NGC games digitally (as of 2020-12-04). The earliest digital copies sold by Nintendo (ignoring handhelds) were WiiWare games on Wii, and a selection of Wii games on Wii U. Some NGC games were ported to the Wii to take advantage of the Wii's motion controls (such as Pikmin 1 and 2 and Metroid Prime 1 and 2), but Pokémon XD is not one of those games.
- [The Wii Shop Channel was discontinued on 2019-01-30](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27560/%7E/wii-shop-channel-discontinuation), so there is no legitimate way to download *any* game on Wii any more.

Comment: but isn't it available for the gamecube?

Comment: @mysticwill, NGC = Nintendo GameCube. The game can be played on NGC and Wii, but NGC games were never sold digitally, so there's no legitimate website where you can download the game. You'll need to find a physical copy instead.